# Selecting permutationally-unique elements of a symmetric tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, combinatorics

I have a code which creates a numpy array `A` of shape `(m, m, ..., m)` where there are `n` copies of `m`. By construction, this array is a symmetric tensor (in the mathematical sense), meaning that `A[i, j, ..., k] == A[i', j', ..., k']`, where `(i', j', ..., k')` is a permutation of `(i, j, ..., k)`.

We may define the permutationally-unique elements of `A` as the set of entries in `A` whose corresponding indices are not equivalent to one another by permutation. For example, in a matrix with shape `(3, 3)`, the permutationally-unique indices are `(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)`.

For a general symmetric tensor `A`, how can I extract all of its permutationally-unique elements, as well as their corresponding indices? (`np.unique` doesn't work, in the case where two elements `A[i1, j1, ..., k1]` and `A[i2, j2, ..., k2]` are equal by coincidence, but `(i1, j1, ..., k1)` is not a permutation of `(i2, j2, ..., k2)`.)

Comment: I'm not sure you've given enough detail for anyone to answer this question. Consider providing a small example to explain things.

Comment: @jared Just added an example for (3x3) matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your tag contains numpy, there is a faster solution on large array:

```py
def combinations_with_replacement_(m, n, dtype=int):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('n must be non-negative')
    if m < 0:
        raise ValueError('m must be non-negative')

    if n == 0:
        return np.empty((1, 0), dtype)

    shape = (math.comb(m + n - 1, n), n)
    out = np.zeros(shape, dtype)
    out[:m, -1] = np.arange(m, dtype=dtype)

    lengths = np.arange(1, m, dtype=np.intp)
    start = m
    for col in reversed(range(1, n)):
        block = out[:start, col:]
        for i, length in enumerate(reversed(lengths), 1):
            stop = start + length
            out[start:stop, col:] = block[-length:]
            out[start:stop, col - 1] = i
            start = stop
        lengths = lengths.cumsum()

    return out
```

For small arrays, there are some tricky acceleration methods, but they have some loss of readability:

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain


def comb_with_rep_faster_on_small(m, n, dtype=int):
    it = combinations_with_replacement(range(m), n)
    flatten = chain.from_iterable(it)
    buffer = bytes(flatten)
    return np.frombuffer(buffer, np.uint8).astype(dtype).reshape(-1, n)
```

---

A simple solution for comparison:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement


def comb_with_rep(m, n, dtype=int):
    return np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(range(m), n)), dtype)
```

Benchmark:

```
import perfplot

funcs = [
    comb_with_rep,
    comb_with_rep_faster_on_small,
    combinations_with_replacement_
]

perfplot.bench(
    kernels=funcs,
    n_range=list(range(1, 20)),
    setup=lambda n: (7, n),
    equality_check=np.array_equal
).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: one way to do so is to select all the indices `(i_1, i_2, ..., i_n)` with `i_1 <= i_2 <= ... <= i_n`. The pseudocode is:

```
def perm_unique(m):

  index_list = []
  
  for i_1 in range(m):
    for i_2 in range(i_1, m):
      ...
        for i_n in range(i_{n-1}, m):
  
          index_list.append([i_1, i_2, ..., i_n])

  return index_list
```

Note: The pseudocode above requires knowing `n` in advance. A better solution would be to make `n` an argument of `perm_unique()`, but that requires recursion, and I am not sure what's the best way to do so.

---

Turns out the solution is surprisingly simple. The code below does exactly that:

```
index_list = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(m), n))
```